# How does Spring split the beans for the same project into multiple Java processes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm working on a project that will have multiple processes for our application. For example, `inputHandler` and `outputHandler`, both can share some common beans, but it won't share them in most of the time.

Also, I can have 2 `inputHandler` processes, and 3 `outputHandler` processes running on the same machine. Nevertheless, I would like to build and pack them separately, this is not mandatory, but I guess it would also be a good practice, right?

Usually, we load the same context for everything, but now, we would like to be smarter, more memory, and boot, efficient.

How can I split these beans to run efficiently in multiple `java` processes ?

I was thinking about having one package `common` and putting there the `@Bean`s that can be shared among all the processes, and for each process, I would have another package and from there I start to develop it separately. However, I'm not sure about this strategy; before talking to you guys/girls.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your Spring context in a common module but partition your beans by Spring "profiles".

Documentation: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Spring Profiles provide a way to segregate parts of your application configuration and make it only available in certain environments.

So your inputHandler process can use beans in the "inputHandler" profile etc.

```
@Configuration
@Profile("inputHandler")
public class InputHandlerConfiguration {

    // ...

}

@Configuration
// no profile - applicable to all profiles
public class CommonConfiguration {

    // ...

}
```

You control which profiles are active by setting the `spring.profiles.active` property. You can have multiple profiles active separated by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Spring's Active Profiles](https://dzone.com/articles/using-spring-profiles-xml) to help you partition you Spring beans.

Spring's documentation on [Active Profiles](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html).